# Purpose of empty brackets in Saltstack state definitions?

Tags: salt-stack, configuration-management

What's the purpose of empty brackets after SaltStack state definitions?

For example, [somewhere in SaltStack documentation](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html#direct-requisite-and-requisite-in-types) you'll see this:

```
vim:
  pkg.installed: []
```

Yet enforcing, for example, `vim` installation could also be expressed like so:

```
vim:
  pkg.installed
```

.. and indeed, [elsewhere in SaltStack documentation](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.pkg.html) that is the prevailing format. So what do the empty brackets signify? Explicitly stating that there are no further parameters for that statement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer to your question is: yes. They just explicitly state that there are no additional parameters to `pkg.installed`.

The long answer:
Salt .sls format is basically a YAML with Jinja templates on top. This means each item in the configuration is either a sequence or a collection. In your example `pkg.installed` has number of optional parameters that can be supplied as a sequence of collections ( think of it as of array of dicts in other programming languages ). For example you could've make the `vim` version fixed like this:

```
vim:
  pkg.installed:
    - version: 1.0
```

YAML allows two syntaxes for writing down sequences and collections. The one described above can also be written as:

```
vim:
  pkg.installed: [{version: 1.0}]
```

In your example the `pkg.installed` does not have any additional parameters supplied and that's explicitly shown with empty square brackets.